# Generate drop down list in YII

Tags: php, yii

I have a table named event(ename,many_other_attributes) where event is the primary key.

I want to generate a drop down menu in YII which includes all the enames in the list.

I am a newbie to YII. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
echo $form->dropDownList(
    $model,
    'land_id',
    CHtml::listData(Event::model()->findAll(), 'ename', 'ename')
);
```